# SSRS report error-Object disconnected

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-grouping

I have an SSRS report which uses 4 datasets retrieving appox 1000 records each.
These records are presented in SSRS using grouping (row wise / column wise) to generate group counts and perecentages.

There are 4 such tables.

The procedures used to fetch data run in less tha 30 sec when run in SQL Server but the report takes much time to render:-

```
TimeDataRetrieval   TimeProcessing  TimeRendering
1250648             219             214
```

The behaviour is:-

In Visual Studio it is giving the error:-

> Object has been disconnected or does not exist at the server.

When deployed in local it is at times rendering the report but taking 10 min or more.

Could you please suggest what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a "parameter sniffing" issue.  Try adding OPTION (RECOMPILE) to the end of your SQL code.